# Use core-data and sqlite c based api simultaneously on same db

Tags: ios, multithreading, sqlite, core-data, fmdb

AFAIK CoreData can be configured to use sqlite in the persistent store.

so as core-data not provides way to query using SQL.

So core-data has sqlite db in background.

Is it safe to access same db using Core-Data and Sqlite c based api same time?

Will it lead to any data corruption is sqllite or any threading issues.

the reason why am I going to use any wrappers such as FMDB or C based API is to query complex data using sql query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably safe but it's still a really bad idea. Core Data defines its own schema, which is undocumented and which is different from what you would use if you designed a SQL schema. So you'd have to create the Core Data model and then reverse-engineer your own schema to make direct SQL calls.

Also, of course, it's going to be an absolute pain in the ass to keep changes in sync across completely different calling styles.

This is a bad idea, even if it doesn't corrupt your data. You will regret using this approach.

Comment: core-data defines its own schema ... I don't understand this part.. in background core-data uses sqlite only .. so the objects would have been converted into tables and its attributes as columns .. so how it would be hard to write own sql for that ....can you explain for me

Comment: Core Data entities are converted to SQLite tables, but Core Data does more than that for its own internal use. The actual scheme will be similar to the data model, but there will be other extra details that aren't documented but that must have correct values for Core Data to use the file.

Comment: and those extra details can and will change in the future.

Comment: BUt anyhow we can interact with sqlite-able by the entity name and attriubtes right

Comment: The table and field names will not match the names used in the Core Data model.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this in the past, before concurrency and subquery expressions existed. I had to make Core Data save everything to disk before using sql. It worked then but you never know if it will work in a future OS X. Nowadays I wouldn't do it. If you need complex queries, use Sqlite only or use Core Data and be creative with predicates and fetch requests.